# get tagged contact from CalendarEvent

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

Does anyone know how to get a "tagged contact" from a google calendar event?

A "tagged contact" can be added via the google calendar android app, but I don't see it anywhere on the CalendarEvent object (or the google calendar web app).  Their [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event) show some "tag" methods, but they do not seem to be related to this "tagged contact".

Comment: I've browsed the documentation but it seems that it is not yet supported. However, you can file a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=823906) for this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I appreciate it.